# Lets not sweat it

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "lets not sweat it" in [this post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/82/190)?

Is it something like "let's not take it too seriously?" or "hey man, take it easy?".

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sweat) defines it pretty clearly.

Comment: As in what, something like “My servant lets not sweat its toll upon his sunny disposition take”?  This message brought to you courtesy of the Apostrophic Jihad.

Comment: @tchrist, is the cited sentence without error? The "take" at the end of it doesn't seem to fit there...

Comment: @Tomas Yes, it is without error.  It has poetic inversion.

Comment: @thchrist your citation is a different usage. Why confuse Tomas? Tomas - the dictionary reference is correct. Also note, this is an Americanism